# Knit a word document with Rmarkdown. in a for loop Inserting a plot between 2 subtitles generates a problem

Tags: r, r-markdown

In Rmarkdow. I want to make a word with different graphics from a for loop.
This document has several sections and subsections. When I insert a block between 2 sub-sections the title following the graph is not in the correct format.

Can you help me ?

When the plot is at the end of the loop no problem

````
```{r pressure,fig.width=6,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results="asis"}

attach(airquality)
for(i in unique(Month)) {

cat("  \n#",  month.name[i], "Air Quaility  \n")
cat("  \n##",  month.name[i], " Subtitle1 Air Quaility  \n",sep="")
  plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,])
cat("  \n")
}
```
````

But if it is between 2 subtitles the last subtitle is not in the correct format in the Word document.

````
```{r pressure,fig.width=6,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results="asis"}

attach(airquality)
for(i in unique(Month)) {

cat("  \n#",  month.name[i], "Air Quaility  \n")
cat("  \n##",  month.name[i], " Subtitle1 Air Quaility  \n",sep="")
  plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,])
cat("  \n##",  month.name[i], " Subtitle2 Air Quaility  \n",sep="")
cat("  \n")
}
```
````

Result in Word:

### May Air Quaility

### May Subtitle1 Air Quaility

[plot]

'##May Subtitle2 Air Quaility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the solution is simple just add `cat("\n")` after the plot:

````
```r
attach(airquality)
for(i in unique(Month)) {

cat("  \n#",  month.name[i], "Air Quaility  \n")
cat("  \n##",  month.name[i], " Subtitle1 Air Quaility  \n",sep="")
  plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,])
cat("\n")
cat("  \n##",  month.name[i], " Subtitle2 Air Quaility  \n",sep="")

}
```
````